# Azure Cognitive Search in Python using Vector embeddings Error

Tags: azure, search, vector

I am trying to use Azure Cognitive Search for Vector search. Trying to use the python sdk and I am getting an error saying ImportError: cannot import name 'Vector' from 'azure.search.documents.models'.

I did install azure-search-documents using pip and it is the latest version. Any pointers on what I am missing here.

Using the github sample on creating a vector store in Azure Cognitive Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search for Vector search is available only for private preview . If you want to use it, you need to install specific version.
**azure-search-documents==11.4.0a20230509004**

for more info: refer this link https://github.com/Azure/cognitive-search-vector-pr/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Hacker's answer. Newer preview versions also work. Therefore below command should also solve your problem:

```
pip install azure-search-documents==11.4.0b6
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work while you've already chosen other versions. Try changing the **kernel**, that worked for me after trying all the versions of azure-search-documents and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided above has the answer. The problem you are facing is because the latest version of
`azure-search-documents==11.4.0` 
doesn't have the Vector class anymore instead we have to use VectorizedQuery as provided in the above link shared.

Earlier preview versions had this Vector class.
For eg: `azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8`

So you have to update to latest which is always better and update code to use VectorizedQuery instead of Vector. The search_client also takes a new parameter **vector_queries** instead of earlier **vectors**

##### Sample Code with latest azure-search-documents

```py
from azure.search.documents.models import VectorizedQuery
...

vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=get_embeddings(query), k_nearest_neighbors=3, fields="descriptionVector")

    results = search_client.search(
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["hotelId", "hotelName"],
    )
```

Source : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/samples/sample_vector_search.py#L139